# Solve the differential equation $x^2u'=0$ in the sense of distributions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

> Solve the differential equation in the sense of distribution:
>   $$x^{2}\frac{du}{dx}=0$$

This is from "Principles of Applied Mathematics" by Keener, problem 4.1.5.
The solution in the back of the text is 
$$u(x)=c_{1}+c_{2}H(x)+c_{3}\delta(x)$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.
I think that I understand what the solution means (the action of $u$ on test functions), but I do not understand how to arrive at such a solution.

Comment: That solution is incorrect.  The solution is given by $u(x)=\frac13 x^3+C$

Comment: I have corrected a typo. I am trying to solve the weak formulation of  $x^{2}\frac{du}{dx}=0$, where $u$ is treated as a distribution.

Comment: The factor $x^2$ only influence the solution at $x=0$ so $du/dx$ can only contain delta’s (and it’s derivatives). Since $\delta’(x) = -\delta(x)/x$ and $\delta(x)x = 0\implies x^2\delta’(x) = 0$ we get $du/dx = A\delta(x) + B\delta’(x)$. Likewise if it was $x^n du/dx = 0$ we would have $du/dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} A_i \delta^{(i)}(x)$. Integration of this expression using $dH(x)/dx = \delta(x)$ gives the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Following Keener's example 2, on page 143 of the year 2000 edition.

We want to find a distribution $u$ such that :

$<x^2 u',\phi>=0$ for all $\phi \in D$, where $D$ is the set of test functions.

Which is equivalent to

$-<u,(x^2\phi)'>=0$ for all $\phi \in D$.

or $<u,\psi>=0$ for any test function $\psi$ such that $\psi=(x^2\phi)'$.

Now, it is not hard to see that:

**Lemma**: Given $\psi,\phi \in D$, then one can write $\psi=(x^2\phi(x))'$ if and only if $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi(x) dx=0$, $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \psi(x) dx=0$, and $\psi(0)=0$.

Assume the lemma, and pick $\phi_0(x),\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x) \in D$ such that:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi_i(x) dx=0$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi_i(x) dx=1$ for $i=0$.

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi_i(x) dx=0$ for $i\in\{0,2\}$ and 
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi_i(x) dx=1$ for $i=1$.

$\phi_i(0)=0$ for $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $\phi_i(0)=0$ for $i=2$.

Note that for any $\phi \in D$, we can write

$\phi(x)=\phi_0(x) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds + 
\phi_1(x) \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds + \phi_2(x)\phi(0)+\psi(x)$.

Where $\psi(x)=\phi(x)-\left(\phi_0(x) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds + 
\phi_1(x) \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds + \phi_2(x)\phi(0)\right)$

Show that $\phi(x)$ satisfies the three conditions of the lemma.

Then from $<u,\psi>=0$  where $\psi=(x^2\phi)'$ you get that 
$<u,\phi(x)>=<u,\phi_0(x) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds > + <u,\phi_1(x) \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(s) ds >+ <u,\phi_2(x)\phi(0)>$

Or equivalently

$<u(x),\phi(x)> = <c_1 H(x) + c_2 \delta_0(x) + c_3 ,\phi(x)> $ for all $\phi(x) \in D$.

Therefore $u(x)=c_1 H(x) + c_2 \delta(x) + c_3$ in the distributional sense, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v=du/dx$. The expression $x^2 v =0$ means that for every test function $\phi$, the distribution $v$ vanishes on $x^2 \phi$. It follows that $v$ vanishes on all test functions $\phi$ such that $\phi(0)=\phi'(0)$, because these can be written as $\phi=x^2\psi$ with $\psi$ another test function.  Hence 
$$
v(\phi) = c_1\phi(0)+c_2\phi'(0)
$$
which can be written as $v$ being a linear combination of $\delta$ and $\delta'$. Integration yields $u$ being a linear combination of $H$ and $\delta$, plus a constant.